# Retrofit 2 PHPSESSID changed

Tags: php, android, retrofit

I start using Retrofit 2.  I found that my PHP session id is changed when I have a new activity or fragment.  How to keep the same session?

Also, I want to post the same session id each post.  This is my code.  Is it correct?

```
Call<HistoryModel> getMessage(@Header("Set-Cookie") String sessionid, @Field("message") String message);
```

where

```
sessionid = "PHPSESSID="+session_key
```

I know I can get the result from response.body() but how can I log the send data?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem.   My code is correct but the session_key was incorrect.   In Retrofit 2, we can get headers value.  Since the return value is an array, I need to remove the "[....]" square brackets.

```
String sessionid  = response.headers.values("Set-Cookie").toString().replace("[","").replace("]","")
```

then I can keep the same session id in all fragment/activity.

Comment: please let em know more about session id. How to send custom PHPSESSIONID using retrofit 2.0